# Composer can't resolve dependency of simplesamlphp

Tags: symfony, composer-php, simplesamlphp

I want to install a [bundle](https://github.com/hslavich/SimplesamlphpBundle) which has the following dependencies:

```
 "require": {
    "symfony/symfony": ">=2.4",
    "simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp": "dev-master"
},
```

When I try to do do the `composer require hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle dev-master` I get the following:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.  
Problem 1
    - simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp v1.13.2 requires openid/php-openid dev-master#ee669c6a9d4d95b58ecd9b6945627276807694fb as 2.2.2 -> no matching package found.
    - simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp v1.13.1 requires openid/php-openid dev-master#ee669c6a9d4d95b58ecd9b6945627276807694fb as 2.2.2 -> no matching package found.
    - simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp v1.13.0 requires openid/php-openid dev-master#ee669c6a9d4d95b58ecd9b6945627276807694fb as 2.2.2 -> no matching package found.
    - simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp v1.12.0 requires openid/php-openid dev-master#ee669c6a9d4d95b58ecd9b6945627276807694fb as 2.2.2 -> no matching package found.
    - hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle dev-master requires simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp dev-master -> no matching package found.
    - hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle dev-master requires simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp * -> satisfiable by simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp[v1.12.0, v1.13.0, v1.13.1, v1.13.2].
    - Installation request for hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle[dev-master].
```

But if I first do `composer require simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp dev-master` and then `composer require hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle dev-master` everything is ok.

How should the bundles composer.json file modified so that I would not need separate require for `simplesamlphp dev-master`?

Comment: Your minimum stability is probably set to `stable` which means that you need to specify any `dev` packages. If that is the case you could either do what you have done or change your minimum stability.

Answer (score 1):

hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle v1.13 requires simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp 1.13

But simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp v1.13.2 requires openid/php-openid: dev-master#ee669c6a9d4d95b58ecd9b6945627276807694fb as 2.2.2

Add in your composer.json:

```
"hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle": "1.*",
"openid/php-openid": "dev-master#ee669c6a9d4d95b58ecd9b6945627276807694fb"
```

The last line is required because openid/php-openid dev-master is not stable.

For your information, gmp PHP extension is required by penid/php-openid.

Answer (score 1):

If you require another package, that requires **another unstable** (dev-master) package, you need to mention **it** in your `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle": "~1.13",
    "simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp": "dev-master"
}
```

Then run:

```
composer update
```